# gradle build failed when adding firebase ML vision

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-mlkit

I add this line in my `build.gradle(:app)`, then failed.

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
```

below is the error message:

```
    In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.
2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-co
mmon@[19.0.2], but play-services-vision-common version was 19.1.0.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@{strictly 24.1.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@{strictly 19.1.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-bom@26.0.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label@{strictly 18.0.4}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@{strictly 20.0.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-bom@{strictly 26.0.0}

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }" to your bu
ild.gradle file.
```

I also try [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#bom_v25-8-0), but still not works.
how to fix this problem? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

we made some changes to Firebase ML Kit for Firebase to better distinguish the on-device APIs from cloud based APIs. "ML Kit"(without firebase branding), contains all the on-device APIs. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration) the migration guide from firebase mlkit to mlkit.

For this specific dependency issue, there is an known issue with the firebase mlkit dependency. Could you try [this fix](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#mlkit-self-serve-fixes) to see it it works for you?

Answer (score -1):

I have been experiencing the same issue. I tried the method listed below and it seems to build but have not done any further testing.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1904#issuecomment-692881749

Comment: Could you try the new MLKit for your feature? Below are the dependency needed for each feature. You can delete the firebase ones in your gradle file.  For more information, you can  check https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/android                                                    
Barcode scanning com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:16.0.3
Face contour com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.0.2
Image labeling com.google.mlkit:image-labeling:17.0.0
Object detectio com.google.mlkit:object-detection:16.2.1

Answer (score -2):

THIS WORKED FOR ME :
change your version to this and its compatible now

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.1'
```

go to this site and see fix : https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#mlkit-self-serve-fixes